# Django Error TemplateSyntaxError only occuring in production

Tags: python, django, nginx, mezzanine

So I've got either a doozy of an issue, or I'm over looking the obvious.

I am getting a TemplateSyntaxError and it's only occurring in production. I temporary turned on DEBUG and it provided zero useful information. I have an index.html page, that loads my tags, it then calls the inclusion tag.

My setup is Django 1.6.5 and using the default Mezzanine setup. (Fabric, Nginx, Gunicorn). Development environment is OpenSuse 12.2 and the deployment environment is some version of Ubuntu (hosted on AWS EC2).

This issue only occurs on the production side and NOT in the development environment. Originally I made the tag a regular tag, and it wasn't even being called at all. The server would silently fail, and act as though it had never attempted to call the tag. (I used logging to prove that it never went into the tag). Now that it is an inclusion_tag (which is what it should be), I get this exception.

Here is the file system paths where the relevant pieces are.

```
project
  bactt_core
    templates
      base.html
      index.html
      blog
        includes
          blog_post_list_include.html

    templatetags
      __init__.py
      bactt_blog_tags.py
```

The error exactly is

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /

Invalid block tag: 'get_blogs_by_category', expected 'endblock'
```

Here is the portion of my index.html template where I am making the call to the inclusion tag. It is dying on the get_blogs_by_category, which is an inclusion_tag. Inside bactt_blog_tags.

```
  <div id="news" class="row">
        <div class="panel">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <h2>News</h2>
                {% load bactt_blog_tags %}
                {% get_blogs_by_category "News" %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is bactt_blog_tags

```
from django import template
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist
#from mezzanine import template
from mezzanine.blog.models import BlogPost, BlogCategory



register = template.Library()
MAX_BLOG_POSTS_TO_RETURN = 5

@register.inclusion_tag('blog/includes/blog_post_list_include.html')
def get_blogs_by_category(categoryTitle):
    category = None
    postList = []
    try:
        category = BlogCategory.objects.get(title__exact=categoryTitle)
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        return {'blog_posts':[]}
    if category:
        for post in BlogPost.objects.all():
            categories = post.categories.all()
            if category in post.categories.all():
                postList.append(post)
    if len(postList) > MAX_BLOG_POSTS_TO_RETURN:
        postList = postList[0:MAX_BLOG_POSTS_TO_RETURN]
    return {'blog_posts': postList}
```

Thanks for any help you can provide I've already spun my wheels for a least a few hours now.

Edit:
So I renamed the file bactt_blog_tags.py to bb_tags.py and everything now works. I have no idea what the reason for this naming issue is but if somebody could explain that, I would definitely call this answered. Why whatever pathing occurs in development vs. production is also odd.

Comment: Where is MAX_BLOG_POSTS_TO_RETURN defined?

Comment: Sorry I copied and pasted the relevant sections. It's at the top of bactt_blog_tags file with a bunch of other constants.

Comment: You say it works in local dev, but have you tried setting DEBUG=False locally? If things then blow up locally, that should make debugging much easier

Comment: Setting it to DEBUG=False locally did not make changes. I had to alter my AllowedHosts (obviously), but once I did that, everything popped up, and I can see the News category of blog posts. I am curious if somehow it's just not finding the templatetags for some reason, or something behind the scenes is causing it to crash. When I had them as regular tags, they wouldn't be called, and I received no exceptions.

Comment: So it seems to be the naming of the template tag file that is causing the problems. I changed it to bb_tags and all of a sudden it works, no problems. It's exclusively the name of it. Any reason why?

Comment: I did think it was the uppercasing, and should have said it earlier. An acceptable answer is below, to help others in the future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What ended up being the fix was changing the name of the template tag filename.

It seems that for some reason using bactt_blog_tags.py created some sort of issue, or possible collisions, that were only happening in production.

What is odd to me is that I didn't have any applications called bactt_blog that might have conflicted. The application directory was bactt_core.

I changed the name to bbtags.py and everything worked.

Comment: Spent hours going through templates but your note on the "name change" saved my life! I had a similar problem where I replaced an unmaintained 3rd party app with my own fork and even though it was no longer registered in the project's `settings.py` file, it's existance inside of the virtualenv was enough to cause the issue. A quick uninstall/re-install of dependencies fixed the problem for me!

Answer (score 0):

Your `TemplateTags` directory should be called `templatetags`.

Django is case-sensitive here because it's a Python module name (hence the `__init__.py` in the template tag dir).

You also have an uppercase letter in your Templates dir, but that doesn't matter as it's evaluated as part of a filesystem path, not as a Python import.

Comment: Sorry I should have put exactly the correct file names in. I went back and updated to exactly what the names are on the system. They are lower cased. Like I said it works in development, not in production, so a simple issue like this, should have crashed regardless. Good eye though.

Comment: Cleaned your *.pyc files locally?

Comment: Yes. I made sure to continually clean them as I was testing them on both the local and server side. I'm not entirely sure why but the filename clearly was the culprit, changing it fixed it. I made an edit update on the bottom of the original question that explains it.